# How can I disable mac's three finger drag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macos

```js
window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => console.log('up'));
```

Try it on a mac, while three finger drag enabled. Drag with three fingers, and watch the ~1 second delay between you release, and the mouseup listener to fire (and log `"up"` to the console). Tried with touchpad click-drag, mouse drag, both on mac and windows, the issue only seems to appear with mac touchpad three finger drag, and it currently messes up my app. Same case if you drag files around in finder for example, just haven't realised it till this point. Couldn't find any ways to detect it. Any ideas?

Comment: I will make a noob proposal, although this has nothing to do with touch, can you inspect event.touches during 3 finger drag to see if it is populated

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately trackpad touch isn't recognised as a touch event

Comment: wait a second, in your example snippet, what did you mean by try it on mac? you mean the mouseup does not fire ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realised that I haven't actually explained the issue. Updated the question, but the issue is that it fires, but there's a 1s delay.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the native MAC event

If you want to prevent the even on MAC you need to identify if it is a MAC computer and then set overflow hidden for your div or do what you need to do.

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you could do something like this:

```
var isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')>=0;

//logic here to prevent the drag
```

Comment: The issue is that it's a UI design tool, so the expected behaviour is to drag, but release immediately after the user releases the trackpad